# Using a when clause in an enum class getter in Kotlin

Tags: enums, kotlin, switch-statement, getter

I'm trying to get a specific getter of a property in kotlin to be based on the value of the enum it is called from. This is what I got so far:

```
enum class Endpoint {
    EVENTS, GAMES;

    val baseUrl = "https://www.example.com/api"

    val path: String
        get() = when(this){
            EVENTS -> "$baseUrl/events"
            GAMES -> "$baseUrl/games"
        }
}
```

Called like this:

```
print(Endpoint.EVENTS.path)
```

While this compiles without any problem, as soon as I run it I get a `NullPointerException` with the error `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object [...].Endpoint[].clone()' on a null object reference`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or what the proper way to accomplish what is stated above is.

EDIT: Full log of the exception:

```
05-09 22:51:33.793 15673-15673/com.filippovigani.eventvods E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.filippovigani.eventvods, PID: 15673
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.filippovigani.eventvods.networking.Endpoint.getPath(Endpoint.kt:21)
    at com.filippovigani.eventvods.networking.Endpoint.<init>(Endpoint.kt:25)
    at com.filippovigani.eventvods.networking.Endpoint.<clinit>(Endpoint.kt)
    at com.filippovigani.eventvods.networking.EventvodsApi$Companion.getEvents(EventvodsApi.kt:8)
    at com.filippovigani.eventvods.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:19)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object com.filippovigani.eventvods.networking.Endpoint[].clone()' on a null object reference
    at com.filippovigani.eventvods.networking.Endpoint.values(Endpoint.kt)
    at com.filippovigani.eventvods.networking.Endpoint$WhenMappings.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.filippovigani.eventvods.networking.Endpoint.getPath(Endpoint.kt:21) 
    at com.filippovigani.eventvods.networking.Endpoint.<init>(Endpoint.kt:25) 
    at com.filippovigani.eventvods.networking.Endpoint.<clinit>(Endpoint.kt) 
    at com.filippovigani.eventvods.networking.EventvodsApi$Companion.getEvents(EventvodsApi.kt:8) 
    at com.filippovigani.eventvods.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:19) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Can you confirm the versions of Kotlin/Gradle/JVM you are using, I tested your code and it worked

Comment: @jrtapsell kotlin_version = '1.2.41', gradle_version = '3.1.2'. Not sure if it matters but I'm developing with android databinding library.

Comment: I tried with 1.2.41, I still cannot reproduce the error

Comment: Tested on TIO [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVCxbsJADN3vK6yoQyKVZA8FKUPUqV0C3Q11kxN3zunOEBDKt6ch0AJv8/Oz37N3rRjNw0C8t7A1GAKU/O1azQJnBSPKr/JzVb3Ce/FRVnM1cQc0sMFAa29gAVEj4kKeZV3XpXRE6wyl29Zm6HR0H3AoTQ6VeM31RF5Qk8TJuKNriGNpdEjO/727O8yWEL3cHDM6EEuInnRTumdZjZYeVL3qlfrZM1jUHKOvQw6F93h6u0ZaJreD3VhJ/PeF9JogvaRPVD8Mvw "Kotlin – Try It Online")

Comment: This is interesting. I've added the full exception log, maybe it can help to pinpoint what the issue is.

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce your error, the code works fine. Nevertheless, I think the solution is a bit too complex, why don't you use a constructor argument to provide the constant-specific value:

```
enum class Endpoint(service: String) {
    EVENTS("/events"), GAMES("/games");

    private val baseUrl = "https://www.example.com/api"
    val path: String = baseUrl + service
}
```

Comment: You are right, my solution is a lot more convoluted compared to yours. Thank you.

Comment: This is the correct way to accomplish what you're looking for. The values of an enum class are instances of the class and can therefore be initialized by a constructor and even implement their own anonymous classes. You can read more about enums in Kotlin here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html

Answer (score 1):

The exception indicates you're trying to access `path` within the constructor of the enum. This causes a problem because the enum is not yet ready for use during construction.

This means the following chain of calls results in failure:

1. Init `Endpoint`
2. Init `Endpoint.EVENTS`
3. Call to `Endpoint.getPath()` (This does not show in your code)
4. Uses `Endpoint$WhenMapping`, begin init of that class.
5. `Endpoint$WhenMapping` uses `EndPoint.values()`, but since we're still initializing the instances of the enum, the values array cannot be provided, returning `null`.
6. To ensure it is not modified, `WhenMapping` clones and caches the array, but since the array is null when it never should be outside of initialization this causes the NPE.

Simply put your code somehow relies on a class that requires itself to be fully initialized to use. Since your code does not display how you're calling `Endpoint.EVENTS.path` this is all that can be said about it.

Comment: I'm really having a hard time wrapping my head around it. The way I'm calling `Endpoint.EVENTS.path` is with `print(Endpoint.EVENTS.path)` (the log is somewhat different, but for test purposes I just did the print call) in the `onCreate` method of an activity.
However as others have stated, the code works fine for them. Not sure what I'm missing.